# How to handle URLs from Facebook Open Graph actions in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, url-scheme

I'm building an iOS app that has Facebook open graph actions, and when I post an action on Facebook, on mobile app, I'm getting a link to my mobile app's ID on the App Store, which is not available yet. As a placeholder (otherwise Facebook doesn't save my settings), I've put an ID of another app that I have. Whenever I tap an Open Graph story on Facebook from my new app in Facebook iOS app, An App Store page of my previous app opens. I need the functionality to handle open graph action taps from Facebook iOS app before I submit my app to App Store. How can I test URL handling functionality in a such scenario?

Here is how my Facebook Native iOS App dashboard looks like:
[image: ios app]
Bundle ID matches my app's ID in my app exactly. iPhone/iPad App Store ID links to one of my previous apps, else Facebook doesn't accept my settings when I click Save button, complaining about app not yet being available on App Store. Facebook login and deep linking are both enabled, and URL schemes are registered the same way (the one starting with `fb` continues with my Facebook app ID) in the app bundle too. But still, my app doesn't launch when I tap a story on Facebook mobile app. Instead, a popup to install the app with the ID that I've specified launches (though, weird enough, I have that app installed too).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook documents this here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/

Just look under **How to handle deep links to provide a more relevant user experience**

Comment: i know that article, and i've got everything set up. just look at the updated question, i've added a screenshot.